# Token con php get, solo para dar "seguridad" a los visitantes

Tags: php

Necesito lo siguiente:
Redirigir si ?token=etc no está puesto
- http://misitio.com/comprar -> http://misitio.com/comprar?token=etc

Si el token no es valido de acuerdo a la session en php, mostrar echo mensaje de error.

Actualización: En la pagina hay un formulario, el action esta vacio es decir el script se ejucuta el la misma pagina. Debería no generar uno nuevo cada vez que hay un post.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿qué has intentado hasta el momento? ¿con qué problemas te estás encontrando?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro No tengo nada